Raspberry Pi Displaying Load Cell Output from Raspberry Pi on a PHP Webpage?
How to display the output of a load cell connected to a Raspberry Pi on a PHP webpage? I've created a webpage on the Raspberry Pi and want to show the load cell output on it but my code doesn't work. It won't there's no output.
Can anyone help me with this. Thank you
Python Script:
from hx711 import HX711

hx = HX711(dout_pin=5, pd_sck_pin=6)
hx.set_reading_format("MSB", "MSB")
hx.set_reference_unit(1)
hx.reset()
hx.tare()

def read_weight():
    return hx.get_weight()

while True:
    weight = read_weight()
    print("Current weight:", weight)

PHP Webpage:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Load Cell Weight</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Current Weight:</h1>

    <div id="weight"></div>

    <script>

        function updateWeight() {

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML = this.responseText;

                }

            };

            xhttp.open("GET", "get_weight.php", true);

            xhttp.send();

        }

        setInterval(updateWeight, 1000);

        updateWeight();

    </script>

</body>

</html>

PHP Script:
<?php

$weight = exec("python3 read_weight.py");

echo $weight;

?>


Thanks in advance for answering my question.

here is the reload the cell data with python
from hx711 import HX711

hx = HX711(dout_pin=5, pd_sck_pin=6)
hx.set_reading_format("MSB", "MSB")
hx.set_reference_unit(1)
hx.reset()
hx.tare()

def read_weight():
    return hx.get_weight()

print(read_weight())  # Print the weight

php script >>
<?php 
$weight = exec("python 3 read_weight.py");
echo $weight ;
?>

display the output on the webpage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Load Cell Data</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function updateWeight() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_weight.php', // PHP script to fetch data
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#weight').text('Current weight: ' + data + ' grams'); 
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            updateWeight(); // Initial call to fetch data
            setInterval(updateWeight, 1000); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Load Cell Data</h1>
    <div id="weight"></div>
</body>
</html>

